# How do I get Crossy Road mystery character Matt Hall

Tags: crossy-road

How do you get one of the game developers, Matt Hall, in Crossy Road? I have tried a lot of things and I can't figure out how to get him.

Answer (score 2):

According to a quick web search, you can unlock this character like so:

> To get Matt Hall, you need to play through the game as Lucky Cat, which is Matt Hall’s favorite character in the game.
>
> Achieving a high score as the Lucky Cat should unlock Matt Hall in Crossy Road. For those that need help on this, we’ve found a video which shows you the complete process in minutes.

You can read/watch [here](http://www.product-reviews.net/2015/01/19/unlock-crossy-road-secret-character-matt-hall-in-minutes/) - I'm unsure as to whether this is cross-platform (yet). But looks simple enough, so worth a quick test.

Comment: Doesn't work as of today; I'm about to ask another question...

Answer (score 0):

Simply achieve an score of at least 100.

My high-score was and is at 713 and I got him playing Lucky Cat with the score of 105.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail?