# Did the requirements for unlocking developer mascots change?

Tags: crossy-road

Crossy road recently tickled my completionist bone, and I'm in the situation seen in the first attached screenshot - I've managed to collect all of the mascots save three - [Andy Sum](http://crossyroad.wikia.com/wiki/Andy_Sum_(Mascot)), [Ben Weatherall](http://crossyroad.wikia.com/wiki/Ben_Weatherall_(Mascot)), and [Matt Hall](http://crossyroad.wikia.com/wiki/Matt_Hall_(Mascot)). According to the linked wiki pages and various other web searches (and even [Q&A here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/202244/198296)), I should be able to obtain these last characters by approaching or besting my high score using certain other mascots. It doesn't seem to work for me, though. The second attached screenshot shows the end of one attempt; I've had several that meet the requirements I've read online, but no dice...

Have the requirements for unlocking these last three mascots changed?

[image: missing characters]
[image: near-high-score]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might just have been a temporary hiccup. The app was updated last night and it works now.